# Problem with gridview image zoom with updatepanel

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I'm new to asp.net, hopefully this makes sense. I have a gridview in an update panel. I must keep this arrangement to maintain scroll position with a frozen header and no paging. In the gridview I have an image column that zooms with mouse hover. This basically all works. Problem is that when I zoom near the top or bottom of the gridview the image is cropped. It won't expand beyond the panel edge so the image is cut during zoom. I tried to move the image with transform, translate and margins but it only helps for top or bottom, not both. Is there anyway around this? Can I center the image in the panel or allow it to expand beyond the panel edge? I prefer a mouse hover vs a modal window with a close button if that's possible. Here is the markup:

`<asp:Image ID="ImageX" CssClass="zoom" runat="server" Height="122px" ImageUrl='<%#"\Images\" + Eval("ImagePath")%>' Width="150px" />`

and the CSS:

```
.zoom {
    transition: transform .2s;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
       }
    .zoom:hover {
       -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /*IE 9*/
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /*Safari 3-8*/
       transform: scale(3.5) translate(40px, 40px);

                }
```

Also note that the image can be sensitive. If I change settings in CSS the image can flicker like crazy when I mouse out. Thanks.

Comment: if you remove the updatepanel, the image zoom works as expected ?

Comment: Yes it does but then I lose scroll position on selection. In the meantime, I added position: absolute; to zoom-hover and it works better but still at bottom of grid user must scroll to see whole image. Thanks.